# Checking status code in Volley error listener is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am working with Android to connect to server. I am using Laravel for server side. My server side code is working fine because I already tested it. The problem is with checking error status code in error listener of Volley. The status code is always zero when I check it even it is returning 401 exactly when I checked in browser and using other tools.

This is my Volley request return that throw error from server (401 status):

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("STATUS_CODE",CommonHelper.volleyResponseStatusCode(error));
                    if (CommonHelper.volleyResponseStatusCode(error) == 401) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        showMessageDialog("Server error encountered");
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you can see I log the status code.

This is my CommonHelper class with method that check Volley status code

```
public final class CommonHelper {
    .
    .
    .

public static int volleyResponseStatusCode(VolleyError error)
    {
        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
        if (networkResponse != null) {
            return networkResponse.statusCode;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I check the status code, it is always returning 0. Why is this, and how can I check it in correct way?

Comment: Hey why don't you try with postman or any rest client first to check whether server sends such response on failure or not?

Comment: I already tried with other tools. Response is 401 status code. I checked with multiple tools.

Comment: you might want to check it by setting the retry policy if your request time out occurs.

Comment: No no. Request is not timeout. It responses instantly.

Comment: ok. can you try with StringRequest instead of JSONObjectRequest?

Comment: I sent a request with invalid token. That is why it returns 401 status code. If I set valid token, it is working correctly. The problem is with checking status code.

Comment: But the data returned from server is json.

Comment: It's ok, in response you can convert that string to JsonObject. So that is not the issue, but first check with StringRequest.

Comment: I tried string request instead. It returned zero as well. Same result.

Comment: In that case check with your server code, it might happen that server is not passing failure response in result at all. And one more thing you can also check this with the HttpUrlConnection as well to better identify where exactly is the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109443/discussion-between-wai-yan-hein-and-kunalk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with that code. Status code is correctly returned if the server returned stats like 500,400 and so on except 401. But when server returns status code 401, network response is always null. So I just considered like, if the status returned 0, it is equal to 401. That is how I solved the problem with my app.

Comment: We are facing same issue. Can you please help us if you have found solution? It may help us a lot...

Comment: This is the answer I posted. U just consider null as 401. Please read my answer. But now I no longer working on Volley since I moved to retrofit.